# Showing multivariable limit does not exist using sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I want to show that the following limit does not exist, (so that I can show that the function is not continuous)
\begin{equation}\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^4-2y^2}{x^4+y^4}\end{equation}
I want to do this using sequences. So the limit exists if all sequences $z:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus \{0\}$ converging to $(0,0)$ it holds that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(z^{(n)})=L
\end{equation}
So a first sequence I can use is $z^{(n)}=(\frac{1}{n},0)$ which indeed converges to $(0,0)$. Then
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(z^{(n)})=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(1/n)^4}{(1/n)^4}=1
\end{equation}
Now I wish to find another sequence which results in a $L\neq 1$. However I am struggling to find one which satisfies convergence to $(0,0)$. Does anyone know of a sequence which I could use?

Answer (score 3):

Take $\left(0,\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and note that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\frac{0^4-2\left(\frac1n\right)^2}{0^4+\left(\frac1n\right)^4}=-2n^2$$and that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}-2n^2$ does not exist in $\Bbb R$. Actually, this is enough to prove that your limit does not exist.

Comment: Ah I was thinking about that but I wasn't sure that this satisfied what I had to show. Thank you!